# Browser download files directly to external drive without copy to main drive

Tags: hard-drive, browser, external-hard-drive, download, drive-health

From a perspective of preserving the `main drive life` as much as possible,

it would be a good practice to download files directly to an external drive.

```
Browser Settings -> Downloads Directory -> [External Drive Folder]
```

- But how much effective this would really result?:

I read that some browsers **make a copy first on main drive**, and then they put it to the external drive... So this way actuating that good practice would result pretty useless,

as the file's **trace will always remain to the main drive**...

- How this process work technically?
- Is it possible to download directly to external drive, preventing to also copy on main drive?

Comment: Which browser? Which OS?

Comment: @Gantendo On most popular browsers and operating systems

Comment: There are quite a few combinations of popular browsers and operating systems. You can check with Process Monitor on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Drives are meant to be used and not using them (even though spinning in the machine) does not save enough (very insignificant).

> I read that some browsers make a copy first on main drive, and then
> they put it to the external drive... So this way actuating that good
> practice would result pretty useless,

I have not seen this in normal use. I am not saying it cannot happen, but when I save a download to my other machine, there is no trace on the current machine.

I suggest you just use the drive normally.

If the drive is SSD and is a good brand, you likely have 10 to 20 years of writes available.

My laptop has a Samsung SSD with a 600TB write capability. I have written 40 TB after 4.5 years.

My other Insider laptop from 2013 has a 500 GB 7200-rpm hard drive and ran VMware machines for a long time continues to work flawlessly and has never been shown any mercy.

So I suggest that you will be fine using your drive normally.

Comment: Maybe they mean temporary files? It is possible that the browser saves temp files for the download on drive C, and when the download finishes sends it to its intended location D:\.

Comment: I look in my temp folder from time to time and do not see traces of files I put elsewhere. It could possibly happen but I do not see this.